# List missing file names in a pattern

Tags: command-line, files

1. I have a lot of files that start with numbers and are then hyphenated with descriptions.
   For example:

   ```
   001 - awesomesauce
   216 - stillawesomesauce
   ```
2. They are organized by subdirectory

So, how would I using `bash` script or some built-in look inside those directories to see if I am missing a number in order? I.e. report back that I am missing `002`, `128`, etc. in the above example.
I know I can `ls {000..216}\ -*` and it will list the files and throw an error if it doesn't find it, but is there a better way to get JUST the missing files and do it recursively?

Comment: @don_crissti: I won't always know what the range is, but if it makes it possible, I could thoeretically do `ls <dir> | wc -l`?

Comment: That won't help you, it will tell you the number of files not what's the highest number in a file name... I just wanted to know if there's a set number for the range end or is it just the highest no. in a filename...

Comment: @don_crissti: *bonk* of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a `gnu` setup you could run:

```
myarr=( $(find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]*' -printf '%f\n' | cut -c1-3 | sort -n) )
join -v1 <(seq -w ${myarr[-1]}) <(printf '%s\n' ${myarr[@]})
```

---

Alternatively, with `zsh`, you could try something like this:

```
myarr=( **/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*(.one_'REPLY=${${REPLY:t}:0:3}'_) )
mynums=( {001..$myarr[-1]} )
print -l ${mynums:|myarr}
```

It extracts the numbers (the first three digits) from each file name, sorts them and saves the result in an array - `myarr`. It then sets another array - `mynums` containing numbers from `001` up to the value of the last index (i.e. the highest number extracted from the file names) and then uses [*parameter expansion*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to remove the values in `myarr` from the expansion of `mynums`.

Comment: Sadly, I don't use `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [`findmissing` a Python script](https://github.com/Stunner/findmissing) that does this. I developed it on macOS but it should work on any platform. I tested running it with Python 2.7 and 3.6.

Here's is a taste of my script in action:

```
$ cat sampleFile.txt | python findmissing.py -p "DSC003\.(\d+)"
12
13
14
16
17
18
22
23
24
```

...is output when provided the following file:

```
Id                                  Name         Type   Size     Created
1Dgt5ZFKT3zilwPZdiPyPmhM0Y3Fz_xo8   DSC003.010   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 16:57:14
16QPadXBXPGIwiRhzMFRuY7tZkdIlJ1DI   DSC003.011   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 16:54:57
1zD492J3F42Azeoct82DMlXRRuWA8AUiY   DSC003.015   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 17:32:12
1bah8OM_F49BNeoct8M2DlXRRuOD8AUiY   DSC003.019   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 17:24:41
1eZfY4qn3Ol6w1BFafQn6YDy1uOU82NNA   DSC003.020   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 17:21:46
1x-P84Jq1cyuJCW2Opvy4m_qOjOHvAKtA   DSC003.021   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 17:27:16
1O4TjR8Cl31A5qxHkyVmhmukp4dofCO3t   DSC003.025   bin    1.1 GB   2018-06-12 17:36:00
```